# Case sensitive IF formula in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel formula that dells me if I have a duplicate record.

```
=IF(Cell1=Cell2,"Duplicate","Not")
```

My Problem is that i need the operation to be case aware

For Example,  My code would produce "Duplicate" for:

```
Bird = bird
deKalb=Dekalb
aBcDeFg=ABCDEFG
```

I want it to return "Not"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want exact(X, x)  = (false)

"EXACT is case-sensitive but ignores formatting differences."

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/check-if-a-cell-contains-text-case-sensitive-HP010079177.aspx

so:

```
if(exact(cell1, cell2), "dup", "not")
```